# Momentum in rematch in NHL 14

Tags: xbox-360, nhl-14

When playing local game (not an online game), is there any notion of momentum involve in a rematch?

By rematch I mean, after a game, using the `Rematch` option in the quit menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, momentum is only shifted per game. Rematch has no influence on momentum at the start of a game.